# Navbar menu button text styling in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, navbar

I want to keep the text in the Get Quote Button white on downward scrolling. Currently, it changes to grey along with the other navbar font. I need to isolate this button text using custom CSS so it is white at all times, but does not affect navbar menu text.

This is the code I am currently using for the menu font color.

```
.menu-transparent .navbar .nav>li>a {
    color: #fff;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style.

```
.menu-transparent .navbar-fixed-top.navbar.top-nav-collapse .nav > li.getquote > a { color: #fff !important;}
```